# How to use Wait in Selenium-Webdriver with NodeJs and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to do the following:

- Go to Google Search
- Search a random name
- Wait for the page to load
- Go to the bottom of the page
- Click the Next to Next Page

However, in my 'Wait', for some reason, Next  is clicked twice. Is there proper documentation or tutorial on how to use 'Wait' in Selenium-Webdriver with JavaScript?

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

require('geckodriver');
const faker = require('faker');

const searchGoogle = async () => {
    let name = faker.name.findName();
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();

    try {
        await driver
            .manage()
            .window()
            .maximize();
        await driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        await driver.get('https://www.google.com/');
        await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys(name, Key.RETURN);

        await driver.wait(() => {
            until.titleIs(`${name}  - Google Search`);
            driver.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)');
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Next')]")).click();
        }, 1000);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } finally {
        // driver.quit();
        console.log('complete!');
    }
};

searchGoogle();
```